# Spreading $n$ points in $\{0,1\}^n$ as far as possible

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, metric-spaces, hamming-distance

Given a positive integer $n$, the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) $d^H_n(x,y)$ of $x,y\in \{0,1\}^n$ is defined by $$d^H_n(x,y) = |\{k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}: x(k)\neq y(k)\}|.$$ 
We say that a positive integer $s$ is $n$-*spreadable* if there is $T\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ with $|T|=n$ and for $x\neq y\in T$ we have $d_H(x,y) \geq s$. For any integer $n\geq 1$ let $m_n$ be the largest $n$-spreadable number less or equal to $n$.

**Question.** Do we have $\lim \sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{m_n}{n} = 1$?

Comment: No. By flipping all bits on a single coordinate, you can assume 0 in T.  If there are two other vectors in T, the least Hamming distance between the three of them is at most 2n/3.  I suspect the lim sup of your quantity is zero and not one, but I have not thought it through.  Gerhard "The More Hamming, The Merrier" Paseman, 2018.12.30.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, what you're asking is related to the maximum distance of binary codes with large minimum distance $d\geq s$.

In coding theory, $A_q(n,d)$ is defined as the maximum cardinality of a $q-$ary code with length $n$ and minimum distance $d.$

You can never have more than 2 codewords at full distance by binary geometry. In fact,
the Plotkin bound for high distance binary codes states:

If $d$ is even (thus $n$ even for your case) and $2d>n\geq d,$ then
$$
A_2(n,d)\leq 2\left\lfloor \frac{d}{2d-n}\right\rfloor,
$$
which will give $A_2(n,d)\leq 2,$ for your case. Take any vector and it's bitwise complement.

The $d$ odd case is similar, see for Example Roman's book on Coding and Information Theory.

Of course you only want a lim sup tending to 1, and **you can get it to tend to $1/2$** by using the rows of Hadamard matrices for $n$ a power of 2, but I doubt that any value larger than $1/2$ in your expression is achievable (see update below).

**Edit:** Thanks to Aaron Meyerowitz for clarifying the finite odd length case.

**Proposition:** The lim sup is actually $1/2.$

Assume that a value $d$ larger than $n/2$ is achievable. Map the codewords to $\pm 1$ vectors by writing $((-1)^{x_1},\ldots,(-1)^{x_n}).$ The inner product pf two $\pm 1$ valued vectors at hamming distance $d$ from each other is $\delta=n-2d.$ Therefore, if a collection of $m$ distinct $\pm 1$ vectors have minimum distance $d,$ we can write 
$$
0\leq \left| \sum_{i=1}^m u_i \right|^2 = \langle \sum_i u_i , \sum_i u_i\rangle = \sum_i |u_i|^2 + 2 \sum_{i<j} \langle u_i,u_j \rangle \leq mn + m(m-1) (n-2d),
$$
which eventually yields
$$
d\leq \frac{n}{2}\frac{m}{(m-1)}. 
$$
Letting $m=n$ proves the claim.

Comment: Very nice answer, and it's great that you prove the bound is $1/2$!

Comment: So $d \leq \frac{n^2}{2(n-1)}=\frac{n+1}2+\frac1{2n-2}$ and, being an integer, for $n \gt 2 $ even, $d=\frac{n}2$ can't be beat. To achieve that (getting a Haddamard code) requires $n$ to be a multiple of $4.$ That may well be sufficient, but is open.  For odd $n$ one can't beat $\frac{n+1}2.$ In fact one can , for $n=4m-1$, acheive that with $n+1$ vectors, provided that there is a Haddamard code for $4m:$ puncture it by removing a coordinate where all the words agree. Example: for $n=4,d=2$ use $0000,0011,0101,0110$ for $n=3,d=2$ use $000,011,101,110.$

Comment: As far as I can see, the $m^2$ in the rightmost part of the long displayed formula should be $mn$, since each $|u_i|^2$ is $n$, not $m$. Apparently this was just a typo, since the final upper bound on $d$ looks correct.

Comment: you are right I started letting $m=n$ and changed later. thanks

Comment: Is this (incredible) answer entirely new to you, or is there a reference? Thanks.