Maximizing the mutual Hamming distance in $\big[{\cal P}([n])\big]^n$
If $X$ is a set and $A,B\subseteq X$ we let the Hamming distance of $A,B$ be defined as  $d_H(A,B) = \big|(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\big|$. If $\newcommand{\S}{{\cal S}}\S\subseteq {\cal P}(X)$, let the discrepancy of ${\cal S}$ be definied by $\newcommand{\d}{\text{discr}}\d(\S)=\min\{d_H(A,B): A\neq B\in\S\}$.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $X$ be a set and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $[X]^n$ denotes the collection of subsets of $X$ having $n$ elements.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $M_n:= \max\{\d(\S):\S\in \big[{\cal P}([n])\big]^n\}$.
Experiments by Rob Pratt and Claude Chaunier as laid out in the comments below (cheers to Rob and Claude!) seem to point to the following hypothesis:

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k\geq 2$ we have

$M_{2k} = k$ , and
$M_{2k+1} = k$ for $k$ even, and $M_{2k+1} = k+1$ for $k$ odd.


Question. Is the above hypothesis true?

Wouldn't it be worth mentioning @kodlu's upper bound [https://mathoverflow.net/a/319790/127616] which looks like $k+1$ ?

Brute force gives $M_5=2$ and random tests provide the lower bounds $M_6,M_7\geq 3$, $M_8,\ldots,M_{13} \geq 4$, $M_{14},\ldots,M_{16} \geq 5$, and $M_{17}\geq 6$.

Integer linear programming yields $M_2=M_3=M_4=M_5=2$, $M_6=3$, $M_7=M_8=M_9=4$, $M_{10}=5$, $M_{11}=M_{12}=6$.

Thanks @RobPratt! Hypothesis: $M_{2k} = k$ for $k>1$ and $M_{2k+1} = k+1$ for $k>2$?

@DominicvanderZypen $M_9=4\not=5$

@RobPratt Apologies for my sloppiness!

Chuffed (a lazy clause generation solver) says $M_{13}= 6 = k$.

HiGHS linear optimization solver yields $M_{14}=7$ and $M_{15}=M_{16}=8$ by finding valid examples which are reaching kodlu's upper bound $\frac{n^2}{2(n-1)}$.

Thanks @ClaudeChaunier for the effort that you put into this!

You are welcome, it is interesting. Here is a small improvement on Kodlu's upper bound that speeds up proofs and explorations by several magnitudes. When $u_i\in{-1,1}^n$ with $n$ odd, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\in (2\mathbb{Z}+1)^n$ hence $|\sum_{i=1}^n u_i|^2\ge n$. Then if the $n$ sets in $\mathcal{P}(n)$ are all at mutual Hamming distance $d$ or more, we find $d\le\frac{n+1}{2}$ and equality is only possible if the sets are all exactly at the same distance $d$. Add that substantial tight constraint when looking for a solution with minimal distance $\frac{n+1}{2}$ or proving there aren't.

HiGHS again shows $M_{17}=8, M_{18}=9, M_{19} = M_{20} = 10, M_{21} \le 10, M_{23} = 12, M_{25} \le 12$, confirming your guess, as so far it looks like $M_{2k}=k$ when $k\ge 2$ and $M_{2k+1} = k$ when $k$ is even and $M_{2k+1} = k+1$ when $k$ is odd. That suggests the optimal solutions might have general patterns.

Excellent @ClaudeChaunier - I have just updated the hypothesis in the question above.

Here is an elementary proof that $M_n\le \frac{n-1}{2}$ for any $n$ in $4\mathbb{N}+5\;$.
Lemma 1. For any odd $n\ge 3$ and any $n$ vectors $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \dots, \mathbf{u}_n$ in $\{-1,1\}^n$, their pairwise Hamming distances satisfy either
$$d_H(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{u}_j) = \frac{n+1}{2}\quad \text{ for any }i\ne j\qquad(1)\;\;$$
or
$$d_H(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{u}_j) < \frac{n+1}{2}\quad \text{ for some }i\ne j\qquad(2)\;.$$
Proof of Lemma 1. For any odd $m\ge 3$ let us follow kodlu's insight with an additional twist about parity and assume there are some $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and $m$ vectors $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \dots, \mathbf{u}_m$ in $\{-1,1\}^n$ with pairwise Hamming distances $d_H(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{u}_j)$ $\ge d$ for any $i\ne j$. Their inner products satisfy $\langle\mathbf{u}_i|\mathbf{u}_j\rangle =$ $n-2d_H(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{u}_j)\le$ $n-2d$. Since the sum of $m$ odd integers is an odd integer, the components $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ of $\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{u}_i$ are odd integers therefore
\begin{align}n \le \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 = |\mathbf{v}|^2 = \Big\langle\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbf{u}_i\Big|\sum_{j=1}^m\mathbf{u}_j\Big\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m|\mathbf{u}_i|^2 + 2\!\!\!\!\sum_{1\le i<j\le m}\!\!\!\!\langle\mathbf{u}_i|\mathbf{u}_j\rangle&\\
\le mn + m(m-1)(n-2d)&\qquad(3)\;,
\end{align}
which eventually yields
$$d\leq \frac{n}{2}\frac{m+1}{m}\;\qquad\qquad$$
Letting $m=n$ we get
$$d\leq \frac{n+1}{2}\qquad\qquad(4)\;.$$
Now suppose $(2)$ doesn't hold. In other words $d_H(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{u}_j)\ge d$ for $d=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and any $i\ne j$. Suppose $(1)$ doesn't hold either. Then $d_H(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{u}_j)> d$ for some $i\ne j$ and inequalities $(3)$ and $(4)$ become strict, contradicting $d=\frac{n+1}{2}$. Therefore either $(1)$ or $(2)$ must hold. $\blacksquare$
Lemma 2. For any odd $n\ge 3$, if the Hamming distances of three subsets $A,B,C$ of $\{1, 2, \dots,n\}$ satisfy
$$d_H(A,B) = d_H(A,C) = d_H(B,C) = \frac{n+1}{2}$$
then $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3\;$.
Proof of Lemma 2. Take any $a$ in $A$. Without changing any Hamming distance we can simultaneously remove $a$ from $A$
and switch whether $a$ is or is not in $B$ and whether $a$ is or is not in $C$. Therefore we can assume $A = \varnothing$ without loss of generality.
Then $$|B| = d_H(\varnothing,B) = d_H(A,B) = \frac{n+1}{2} = |C|$$ and $$\frac{n+1}{2} = d_H(B,C) = |B|+|C|-2|B\cap C| = n+1-2|B\cap C|$$ so that $n+1 = 4|B\cap C|$ and finally $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3\;$. $\blacksquare$
Back to our main claim. We know $M_n\le \frac{n+1}{2}$ for any odd $n\ge 3$ from kodlu's result. Now suppose $M_n = \frac{n+1}{2}$ for some $n$ in $4\mathbb{N}+5$. Then $(1)$ would hold in Lemma 1 therefore Lemma 2 would apply and $n$ would be in $4\mathbb{N}+3$, a contradiction. Therefore $M_n < \frac{n+1}{2}$ for any $n$ in $4\mathbb{N}+5$. Dealing with integers, it means $M_n \le \frac{n-1}{2}$.

Thanks for this wonderful answer, Claude! I will wait with accepting for a few days, maybe some tighter bounds emerge.
